# How to improve SQL Server skills if the workplace does not provide opportunities for it?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

So for context, I picked up MS SQL Server because the job required it. Currently, I'm able to do basic querying, and joins.

I hit a roadblock when I researched on how to improve, because the information seems to be overwhelming.

For example, some threads say to learn more about Database Administration while others seems to suggest that pursuing a certification by Microsoft is the way forward. Then I came across Data Engineering which is apparently different from Database Administration.

From what I gather, it looks like I should be working towards becoming a Data Engineer or Database Administrator. However, I'm not sure how I can go about it from where I am currently.

I just want to get better at it, and I'd love to hear what you guys feel is an appropriate way forward.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brent Ozar to the rescue! While you are there check out the many resources they have on their website.

Go to StackOverflow and dig through some of the SQL questions and try to answer some. Even if you don't figure it out you'll learn a ton by trying.

People hiring Data Engineers are usually looking for formal training and education and you might not get far self learning. The name Database Administrator is a bit of a misnomer. Many places use Database Administrator and Database Developer interchably, especially places with heavily data driven systems where most business logic in the database. If you are interested in working with the data, and structuring the data, you probably want Database Developer, if you prefer maintaining the system, performance tuning and such then Database Administrator is the way to go. But like I said there is quite a bit of overlap with both roles.

### Getting Into a Database Administrator Position

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/05/moving-from-help-desk-to-database-administrator/

### How to Get a Junior DBA Job – Part 1

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/04/how-to-get-a-junior-dba-job-part-1/